# How to select indices of rows in numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy

I have the following numpy array `y_train`:

y_train =

```
2
2
1
0
1
1 
2
0
0
```

I need to **randomly** select `n` (n=2) **indices** of rows as follows:

```
n=2 
n indices of rows where y=0 
n indices of rows where y=1 
n indices of rows where y=2
```

I use the following code:

```
n=2
idx = [y_train[np.random.choice(np.where(y_train==np.unique(y_train)[I])[0],n)].index.tolist() \
 for i in np.unique(y_train).astype(int)]
```

Error in my real array `y_train`:

```
KeyError: '[70798 63260 64755 ...  7012 65605 45218] not in index'
```

Comment: you need for i == range(3) in there, and then random.choice(np.where(y_train==i), 2, replace=False), then concatenate or hstack the indices together

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your expected output is a list of randomly selected indices for each unique value in `y_train`:

```
idx = [np.random.choice(np.where(y_train == i)[0], size=2, \
       replace=False) for i in np.unique(y_train)]
```

OUTPUT:

```
[array([7, 8]), array([5, 4]), array([1, 0])]
```

If you want to flatten the arrays into a single array:

```
idx = np.array(idx).flatten()
```

OUTPUT:

```
array([7, 8, 5, 4, 1, 0])
```

Answer (score 1):

One alternative solution to get the desired indices is using `nonzero` and simply looping over `range(n+1)`

```
y_train = np.array([2,2,1,0,1,1,2,0,0])

indices = [np.random.choice((y_train==i).nonzero()[0], 2, replace=False) for i in range(n+1)]
print (indices)
# [array([7, 3]), array([5, 4]), array([0, 1])]

print (np.array(indices).ravel())
# [7 3 5 4 0 1]
```